# Finding marginal CDF from a joint PDF and CDF

Tags: probability

> The number of users logged onto a system, N and the time T until the next user >logs off have joint probability given by:
>
> $$P(N=n,X\leq t)=(1-p)p^{n-1}(1-e^{-n\lambda t}), n=1,2,\dots, t>0$$
>
> Find the marginal PMF of $N$ and the marginal CDF of $X$.

I'm stuck at finding the CDF of $X$. To find the PMF of $N$, I simply find $P(N=n, X\leq \infty)$ right? And to find the CDF of $X$, I have to find $P(N=n, X \leq t)$ for all n right?

So since $n$ is discrete,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)p^{n-1}(1-e^{-n\lambda t})=\frac{1-p}{p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n(1-e^{-n\lambda t})$$

But I have no idea how to continue on from here. Unless I'm approaching the question wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard way (assuming throughout that $0\le p<1$):
\begin{align*}
P(X\le t)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(N=n, X\le t)=\frac{1-p}p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^n(1-e^{-n\lambda t})\\&=\frac{1-p}{p}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(pe^{-\lambda t}\right)^n\right)
\\&=\frac{1-p}{p}\left(\frac1{1-p}-1-\frac{1}{1-pe^{-\lambda t}}+1\right)\end{align*} by applying twice the formula of the geometric series. For the first one to converge, we require $0\le p<1$ and for the second one, we require $|pe^{-\lambda t}|<1$ which already follows from $0\le p<1$ and $t>0$. After some rearranging $$P(X\le t)=\frac{1-e^{-\lambda t}}{1-pe^{-\lambda t}}$$ for $t>0$.

---

And, as you said, to find the marginal of $N$, you just have to let $t\to \infty$ which will give you that $N$ has the geometric distribution (starting from $1$) on $\mathbb N_{\ge 1}$.

Comment: Can you explain your first line of reasoning? I see you are using the law of total probability. However, dont you need to multiply the LHF by $P(N=n)$ as well? That is what law of total proability say

Comment: @JimmySabater The law of total probability says that $$P(A)=\sum_{n}P(A\cap B_n)=\sum_{n}P(A\mid B_n)\cdot P(B_n)$$ I take the first form with the intersection (the comma here) of events. The form that you indicate, is with conditioning on $B_n$. Here $A=\{X\le t\}$ and $B_n=\{N=n\}$. Do you agree?

Comment: You are absolutely right now. Sorry for offending.

Comment: as for the second part, dont we get that PMF of $N$ is infinitely? I mean we have 

$$ P(N=n) = \int\limits_0^{\infty} P(N=n, X \leq t ) d t $$
isnt the above integral divergent?

Comment: @JimmySabater No offense. As for the second part, the integral that you indicate is not divergent (expectation of the exponential distribution). But, this is not what we need, since we have $P(X\le t)$ and not $P(X=t)$. Actually, $$P(N=n)=\lim_{t\to\infty}P(N=n,X\le t)$$ Does this make sense?

Comment: I dont understand why do we need to take the limit as $t \to \infty$

Comment: @JimmySabater It is the analogous of summing over all $n$ in the case of $N$. Again, notice that we have $P(X\le t)$ and not $P(X=t)$ because $X$ is a continuous rv. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

$$P\{N=n,X>t\}=P\{N+n\} -P\{N=n,X\leq t\}$$ $$=(1-p)p^{n-1} -(1-p)p^{n-1}(1-e^{-n\lambda t})=(1-p)p^{n-1}e^{-n\lambda t}.$$ Now sum over $n$ to find $P\{X>t\}$.